# Is the A320 family allowed to take off with the flaps retracted?

Tags: takeoff, airbus-a320, flaps, aircraft-operations

Is it legal for the [A320 family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airbus_A320_family) (A318, A319, A320 and A321) to take off without flaps?

An answer to [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/9183/is-it-possible-to-takeoff-without-flaps-extended) states that the A300 can take off without flaps. On the other hand, the 737 family of aircraft is not approved for a no-flap takeoff. (Under the right circumstances, you might survive one, but the margins for losing an engine would be unacceptable, so no data is published for such an operation.)

Comment: The fact that some aircraft can (noted in the linked answer) doesn't mean he A-318/319/320/321 family necessarily can.  Plus, the fact that you might SURVIVE an inadvertant no-flap takeoff doesn't mean it would be legal... while your 2-engine performance might be adequate, engine-out performance might be unacceptable. The linked Q/A never addresses the A-319 family at all... not a duplicate.

Comment: The 737 isn't approved for a no-flap takeoff. You can survive one under certain conditions if everything goes right, but AFAIK there is no published data or procedures for doing so. I don't have an answer for the A319 etc, but the logic to close this as a dupe presumes what I suspect to be the wrong answer as correct.

Comment: The original question referred to "A319 and similar aircraft", hence my earlier comment, but if the question has been changed specifically to refer to the A320 family, then that no longer applies. @RalphJ

Comment: the biggest problem I see for A320 is that maximum tyre speed is 195kts. In clean config, depending on weight and outside condittions, that might not be enough to fly

Answer (score 5):

[image]

For the A320 family it is not allowed. Above shows the takeoff configurations. Anything else and the takeoff warning will be triggered. I also checked the abnormal and special operations, nothing says a 0/0 takeoff is possible.

Each plane is certified for certain configurations. What applies to the A300 or 767 does not apply to all planes.

I took it one step further and [checked the MEL](http://fsims.faa.gov/wdocs/mmel/a-320%20r21.pdf) (ignoring the fact that if the flaps are inoperative, the crew will be in for a treat when it comes to landing). At least one slats/flaps computer is required, and for the flaps/slats to be tested before the flight. The same MEL allows a takeoff if the landing gear can't be retracted.

[image]
(Click to enlarge.)

---

Is it impossible? Of course not. A 737-300 once crash landed on grass, was fixed, and [took-off from that same grass field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TACA_Flight_110). Nothing is impossible. But for the day-to-day operations, the answer is no.