# A320 flap settings

Tags: aircraft-design, flaps

Can anyone please explain about the 5 types of A320 flap settings - Up, Flap 1, Flap 2 and FULL. What do these mean? I've read that the A320 gives 2 outputs for the corresponding flap settings. What does that mean? And what is Flap 1+F?

A320:

Up - 0°/0°
Flap 1- 18°/0°
Flap 1+F- 18°/10°
Flap 2- 22°/15°
Flap 3- 22°/20°
Full- 27°/35

Comment: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/42926/is-the-a320-family-allowed-to-take-off-with-the-flaps-retracted should help (within the first five hits on Google, by the way - and happy Christmas!)

Comment: @CptReynolds thx, that would help! Merry Christmas to you too!

Answer (score 3):

1+F is a configuration with slats at the default position for the flap selector at "1" but with additional flaps extended (10°).

CONF 1+F is selected by positioning the flap lever from up to 1 when speed is below 100 kts or when the flap lever is moved from 2 to position 1.

In CONF 1+F the flaps automatically retract above 210 kts and the selected configuration changes to CONF 1.

As the earlier reply already mentioned the numbers are the slats/flap angles in degrees.

If you need more info I can highly recommend checking out the A320 FCOM e.g. available from http://www.smartcockpit.com/plane/AIRBUS/A320.html

Answer (score 1):

The numbers you listed in the question are slats/flaps. So there is no difference in slat setting between config 1 and config 1+F, and no difference between config 2 and 3.

A good reference for this is "The A320 Podcast" on iTunes/Spotify. There's an episode dedicated to the flap and slat system which explains this really clearly, with the associated failures and procedures.

Answer (score 0):

An A320 has 5 flap positions. 0, 1, 2, 3, and FULL.

Typically, 1+F or 2 and sometimes 3 is used for takeoff depending on operating factors like maneuvering speed, runway length, barometric pressure, weight, OAT, etc.

If you go for Flap 1+F on takeoff then you’d normally retract Flap to 0 at S speed (on PFD speed tape) but since the Airbus is a magical machine, if you fail to retract flap at S speed then auto retraction happens at 210 knots which means flaps are retracted and slats are still extended until you move that lever back to 0.

When in flaps 2, you’d normally choose flap 1 at F speed, then flap 0 at S speed. “O” is green dot speed as shown on the PFD speed tape as a green small dot which indicates the best lift to drag ratio speed or the engine out operating speed in clean config. Not to forget that GD speed is only displayed when in clean config (i.e. flap at 0).

Sorry if all that was overwhelming but good to know since you’re flying that machine on the simulator. Best of luck