# How are the wing control surfaces configured for takeoff?

Tags: wing, flight-controls

For regular aircraft (i.e. a typical airliner), how are the wings configured before or during takeoff? Are there any adjustments needed for climb?

Comment: What kind of adjustments are you thinking of? Do you mean do any of the surfaces move? Or does someone go out with a spanner to adjust parts? Also what procedures for the wings?

Comment: How is your question different from these old ones? https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/9183/1467
https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/1449/1467

Answer (score 5):

Based on environmental conditions (runway length, wind, temperature, etc.) a takeoff flap/slat setting is selected by the pilot prior to takeoff to provide for the required aircraft takeoff and climb profile.

Changing the shape of the wing by deploying takeoff flaps/slats allows the wing to generate greater lift at a slower speed.  Once the aircraft is airborne, as the airplane is accelerated, the flaps/slats are gradually retracted.

[image]

[image]